# Flutter calling a widget from 1 script

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to know if i can make one .dart file with a drawer widget and call that widget from multiple scripts or is there an easier way to have 1 widget over multiple routes i don't wanna have to edit 40 pages to add 1 extra page on my drawer just so i only have to edit one place to add or remove list Tiles. Still not used to how it works entirely yet any info you can share would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not only can but should make your components into separated widgets or files to call them from wherever you want. Just make your Drawer into a Stateless or Stateful Widget and call it like you would any other widget from the flutter framework.

Regarding tutorials, the Flutter website mentions:

[Introduction to Flutter Development with Dart](https://flutter.dev/freecourse) Created in collaboration with the Google's Flutter Team (Beginner).